# [exchangewebservices]Exception calling "Update" with "0" argument(s): "Operation would change object type, which is not permitted."

Tags: directory, exchangewebservices, public

My aim is either to change a public folder folder class or create a new public folder as a contact (not possible with new-publicfolder). so I took some of glens ews snippets.

```
function FolderIdFromPath{
param (
        $FolderPath = "$( throw 'Folder Path is a mandatory Parameter' )"
      )
process{


        ## Find and Bind to Folder based on Path  
    #Define the path to search should be seperated with \  
    $folderid = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::PublicFoldersRoot)   
    $tfTargetFolder = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($service,$folderid)  
    #Split the Search path into an array  
    $fldArray = $FolderPath.Split("\") 
     #Loop through the Split Array and do a Search for each level of folder 
    for ($lint = 1; $lint -lt $fldArray.Length; $lint++) { 
        #Perform search based on the displayname of each folder level 
        $fvFolderView = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderView(1) 
        $SfSearchFilter = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsEqualTo([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderSchema]::DisplayName,$fldArray[$lint]) 
        $findFolderResults =  $service.FindFolders($tfTargetFolder.Id,$SfSearchFilter,$fvFolderView) 
        if ($findFolderResults.TotalCount -gt 0){ 
            foreach($folder in $findFolderResults.Folders){ 
                $tfTargetFolder = $folder                
            } 
        } 
        else{ 
            "Error Folder Not Found"  
            return $null
        }     
    }  
    if($tfTargetFolder -ne $null){
        return $tfTargetFolder.Id.UniqueId.ToString()
    }
}
}
#Example use
$fldId = FolderIdFromPath -FolderPath "\my\folder"

$Subfolderid = new-objectMicrosoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId($fldId) 
$SubFolder = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($service,$SubFolderId)
$subfolder.FolderClass = "IPF.Contact"

$SubFolder.update()
```

Exception calling "Update" with "0" argument(s): "Operation would change object type, which is not permitted."

> $SubFolder.update()
>   Exception calling "Update" with "0" argument(s): "Operation would change object type, which is not permitted."

However, it fails. Is that an permission issue or is something wrong in the source?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is quite confusing to follow but if I'm understanding correctly, you're basically doing a GetOrCreate on a folder with the type "IPF.Contact".  If the folder exists, you try to update the type.

As the error says, you cannot change the underlying type of an object once it's been created.  You may also see this if you use EWS to read a contact item as an email item and then attempt to save it.

You will have to create the folder with the intended type.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to update an existing, empty public folder.
New attempt is to create a new public folder with the correct folder type. I use the same function as before to retrieve the folderid for the parentfolder
Also fails:

```
    $fldId = FolderIdFromPath -FolderPath "\my\folder"
    $EWSParentFolder = $null
    $NewFolder = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder($service)  
    $NewFolder.DisplayName = "test123"
    $NewFolder.FolderClass = "IPF.Contact"
    $ParentFolderId =  new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId($fldId.id)
    $EWSParentFolder = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($service,$ParentFolderId)       
    $NewFolder.Save($EWSParentFolder.Id)
```

error message: Exception calling "Bind" with "2" argument(s): "Id is malformed."
-got it: Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId() has to be initialized with $fldid.id !